# how to detect if camera is being used in the background in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera

I have been trying to explore a way to detect if my camera is being recording in the background like (Access dot in IOS) using camera2 API but i don't seem to get any results

i tried this

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        boolean t = true;

            CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Handler yourHandler = null;
                manager.registerAvailabilityCallback(new CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCameraAvailable(String cameraId) {
                        try {
                            super.onCameraAvailable(manager.getCameraIdList()[0]);
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        txt.setText("available");
                        //Do your work
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCameraUnavailable(String cameraId) {
                      try {
                            super.onCameraUnavailable(manager.getCameraIdList()[0]);
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        txt.setText("unavailable");
                        //Do your work
                    }
                }, yourHandler);
            }
        }
```

but it doesn't seem to work properly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/